# How to setup a webpage for encrypted tunnel

Tags: networking, server, proxy, openvpn

How do I create a home server with a web page that will act as a proxy tunnel?

By tunnel, I mean:

- From some outside computer (client) I will type my home PC's static IP address and there will be a simple web page with, let's say a simple textbox.
- I will type the address of the website I want to access to this textbox and press a button. Then my home PC will retrive the webpage and send content to my client computer, on the same home page.

This can be done with a proxy server, but I don't want to change any proxy settings on the client side browser.

VPN is also not an option because PPTP network config or VPN client software is not allowed.

Client side will have just a simple browser and the only job the client doing will be to connecting to the page on my home servers IP address.

Additonally, content and request information should be encrypted if possible, so that any device between my client and home server should not be seeing any info about what data/website is flowing over network.

PS: This is not a real application, I am trying to learn about network structure of such a system and there is no need for a full explanation. A skeleton of application will be enough.

Comment: why not installing a proxy software like [Glype](https://www.glype.com/) on server?, for that you need a simple apache/php install.

Comment: @bistoco but will I need to configure client side browser for proxy settings? this is not allowed in my case.

Comment: nope, that package is a browser-like proxy, exactly what you want, check it .

Comment: Yeah, indeed it looks like what I *exaclty* want. Thanks. Can you write this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a browser-like proxy software on the server, [Glype](https://www.glype.com/) is one option.

To run it you need a simple apache/php setup.